# express file upload memory issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, upload, express

I host my site on NodeJitsu and am having memory issues with file uploads. My app crashes with this log message:

```
{ [Error: spawn ENOMEM] code: 'ENOMEM', errno: 'ENOMEM', syscall: 'spawn' }
```

It never actually gets to my controller so it's not an issue there. I am currently uploading the file using jQuery POST Ajax. I have also tried chunk uploading using the BlueImp plugin.  The files in question are not that big - jpg images, 1000x1000, normal Kbs, nothing unusual.

I wonder if there is anything I can do to make this work? Some alternate way to upload bypassing Express's standard way, or some setting.

UPDATE: I have tried standard html forms, jquery ajax, blueimp jquery plugin, using native express bodyparser, using formidable. It's a no go. I'm assuming you just can't upload files to nodejitsu that are anything beyond small in size.

Comment: Can you post some code so we have at least some idea of what you are doing.  There are 1,000 ways to handle file uploads with Node.js/Express, and we don't know which you are using.  And, are you spinning up a child process?

Comment: There really isn't any code - standard html multipart form, or jquery ajax post, or jquery chunked upload - whatever. THan Express 3 using bodyParser. My controller is not involved since it's not even hitting it before it dies. Empty controller does the same thing

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I was getting the same problem, but I'd changed my default upload directory. So, I changed it back that to default in express i.e. I changed

```
app.use(express.bodyParser({
        uploadDir: __dirname + "/public/images/tmp"
    }));
```

to

```
app.use(express.bodyParser());
```

Then, I deployed the app, and it worked for me.

You might also want to look at the dependencies in your package.json file.
You can consult this link for detail http://blog.nodejitsu.com/package-dependencies-done-right